# Having more than 1 website on the same IP address makes the primary website to be less crawled?

Tags: seo

Does having more than 1 website on the same IP address makes the primary website to be less crawled?

### Theoretically, let's assume that:

1. A person moves all its sites from shared to dedicated hosting --- He no longer shares the same IP with much more other users as in shared hosting.
2. The [GPI](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) score stays the same like 85/85 (it's 99% unlikely but let's assume that philosophically).

### My question:

Well, my question can actually be comprised of the following 2 questons:

1. Is the fact he no longer shares an IP with say 10,000 people on the shared server, significantly help SEO?
2. If the person would keep only 1 site on this dedicated server (and bring all others to another shared hosting platform) would that ALSO contribute to the SEO by making the primary site be the sole site on the dedicated hosting platform?

Answer (score 3):

The IP address has no impact on how Google assigns its resources. Google treats each domain and sub domain as separate regardless if they are shared on servers with 10,000 websites or just 1. Googlebot resources are assigned based on authority of the site nothing to do with the server apart from page speed which can increase rankings.

A dedicated IP has many benefits but does not directly improve Google's crawl duration or the rate that Google returns to the site.

Comment: Do you have a source for that? I'm pretty sure Googlebot won't start sending 100 simultaneous requests to the same IP just because they are different domains.

Comment: Google doesn't send Googlebot to IP addresses... it sends the bot to the domain. Shared hosting accounts can't be accessed solely on the IP address without server side tricks such as `/~user/` but you know this already. GoDaddy, 123reg, UK2 and so on, don't run shared hosting accounts with just 100 accounts, they often have them in the 10,000's with hundreds of gigs of ram, fast SSD and between 12-32 cores. Viewing SSH and viewing the concurrent users filtered by user agent I've seen over 60 bots at anyone time and that was hosting with only a couple of thousand.

Comment: The majority of the internet is based on shared hosting and to assume that Google won't send 100 bots to a server that can handle 100,000's of concurrent users at one time doesn't seem logical. If Google only sent a few bots at any time to one IP address nothing would ever get indexed. Google allocates resources to domain.

Comment: The only time Google factors IP addresses is during linking schemes i.e class C and even then they haven't officially confirmed that. I say, no need for evidence its common sense since there's no way Google can crawl billions pages sending just few bots at anyone one time. Shared hosting makes up the majority of the internet.

Comment: "Google doesn't send Googlebot to IP addresses... it sends the bot to the domain." -- This is incorrect - Googlebot absolutely does request the IP address, as does every single web browser. The request goes to the IP address with a `Host:` header that has the domain. I still don't see any source for your claims...

Comment: Also, sure there are thousands of sites on a shared server, but there are millions/billions of shared servers. There's plenty of time for Googlebot to make a few requests on one domain, go to some different servers, then come back to a different domain on the first server.

Comment: Me and a friend used to run a shared hosting server but dissolved the company due to loss on our margins through bad math and business sense at the time, so I know a thing or two about that. I have seen concurrent connections personally from Googlebot and I can assure you that a server can have many bots on the server at once. So your need to collect your evidence elsewhere as I do not have screenshots, and official links for you to confirm. But if you think namecheap who has over 30 shared servers with around 300,000 sites has no more than 4 bots viewing each server at one time your wrong.

Comment: Also in regards of my statement about the domains being accessed and not IP I didn't mean what I said and you kinda picked that apart. Google will want to resolve the domain to IP and its unlikely something they want to cache as they most likely want to update their own records for those changes. I'd think it would be easier to prove that Google doesn't crawl a server with many bots at once than prove.

Answer (score 1):

Googlebot will adjust its crawl rate based on the amount of time it takes to download each page.  When there are 10,000 users hitting a server, it may slow the server down significantly and it will not serve the pages as quickly. Even with a high page speed score, a slow slow server can cause Googlebot crawl fewer pages per day.

Other than the server speed, there should be no impact on crawling on a shared server.

Google does not generally use the other sites hosted on the same server as any sort of signal for SEO.  Shared hosting is so common that Google can't usually tell anything about a site based on the other sites with which it shares an IP address.   Other than the server load causing slow pages on an overloaded shared server, there should be no benefit to SEO of moving to a dedicated host.